# The XMLHttpRequest object

Tags: javascript, ajax, object, browser, naming-conventions

I have a few questions about XMLHttpRequest.

1. Is it true that this is not a Javascript object, but an object that
   is native to the browser? This is the first time I have heard of a
   browser having "native objects." What other native objects does a
   browser have?
2. It seems that XMLHttpRequest existed before Ajax. If that is true,
   then what was it used for?
3. It has 5 attributes: readyState, status, onreadystatechange,
   responseText, responsXml. Notice that these are all written in lower
   camel case, except for onreadystatechange. Why is that?

Comment: Native browser objects? `window`, `document`, etc.

Comment: How many of them are there? How can I see them all?

Comment: `console.dir(window)` Anything in there that isn't found in ECMAScript is native to the browser. *(They're called "host objects" in the specification.)*

Comment: @am not i am thats very insightful thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`XMLHttpRequest` first originated by IE, it was later also included in most other browsers including Firefox.

Back then, Microsoft had its own use of the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

It was only sometime in 2005 that the `XMLHttpRequest` object became "discovered", widely known and useful to be able to post data asynchronously to the server without holding user's browser.

The name AJAX was coined using `XMLHttpRequest`.

`XMLHttpRequest` is an enabler of AJAX, which is a combination of this object + XML + JS (Although these days you could arguably say JSON serves the job better than XML)

Answer (score 3):

1. Actually most of the build-in objects/types are native objects/types because of performance reasons, and some of them are native feature related so they have to be native objects/types. They just have JavaScript wrappers and can be accessed by JavaScript.
2. XMLHttpRequest is the base of AJAX, AJAX is a buzz word raised by XHR and finally became a concept like "dynamic, fancy, user friendly client-side webpage".
3. That's the naming convention of "event", like "onclick", "onmouseover". The camel case is for methods. The type convertion for types/classes is pascal case, e.g., "XMLHttpRequest".